# So... What exactly is going on with the elections?

Tags: discussion, election

I haven't been on this site in a while, but I noticed that elections are going on right now. That's really exciting, and I can't wait to see what the new moderators will bring! However, there is one crucial piece of information that I haven't been able to find out anywhere.

> **Why are we having elections?**

This kinda feels like a silly question, but I don't see any answers anywhere.

Are current moderators stepping down or resigning? How many new moderators are being elected? How many moderators will the site have *after* the election?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every so often, the higher-ups at SE will ask the moderation team if new moderators should be added.

New moderators could be added for a number of reasons, such as:

- The site is growing, meaning that the moderation load is growing.
- The current mods could use some extra help shouldering the load.

The current moderation team is staying in place, but we will be adding two more to the moderation team.

I think the current mod team has been handling things okay, but it will be nice to have a couple more folks to assist. It's hard for just two or three people to keep monitoring a site that gets traffic twenty-four hours a day from all over the world.

At the end of the election, there will be five moderators on the team. After seeing a number of excellent candidates add their names to the list of candidates during the nomination phase, I'm looking forward to working with the expanded team.

Comment: Cool, thank you for clarifying this!